# Reading from file then excetuing Js code by calling specific method

Tags: javascript, scriptengine

I made some `.txt` files, which contains only one method of JavaScript. For example the content of `code.txt` is:

```
function method(){

    return 4;

}
```

Now I want to read specific file and execute java script code

This is what I have tried:

```
public class read {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ScriptException {


        ScriptEngine scriptEngine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("js");

        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("code.txt")));

        String content ="";
        String code ="";

        while((content = bufferedReader.readLine())!=null){
            code+=content;
        }
        
        scriptEngine.eval(code);
    }
}
```

I want to get the result from the `method()` and check if returned value is `4`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No result is returned because **ScriptEngine** is not being told to return any value and to invoke specific method. what would we do in situations where we would need to call a method from another script of course we would use [INVOCABLE](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/script/Invocable.html) interface What the interface does is that Calls a method on a script object compiled during a previous script execution which is retained in the state of the ScriptEngine So in your case what you should do is typecast scripEngine to Invocable

```
Invocable invocable = (Invocable)scriptEngine;
```

then calling your function by name with the help of invokeFunction method

```
Object myResult =  invocable.invokeFunction("yourMethodName",null);
```

if u want to check if your returned result was 4 that should be easy with an if condition

```
if(myResult.equals(4)){
     //do something
}
```

Your code fixed

```
public class read {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ScriptException, NoSuchMethodException {


        ScriptEngine scriptEngine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("js");

        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("code.txt")));

        String content ="";
        String code ="";

        while((content = bufferedReader.readLine())!=null){
            code+=content;
        }

        Invocable invocable = (Invocable)scriptEngine;
        invocable.invokeFunction("yourMethodName",null);
        scriptEngine.eval(code);

       if(myResult.equals(4)){
     //do something
}
    }
}
```